# ¡Estamos de enhorabuena! Estado efervescente del sitio y cómo seguir creciendo

Tags: discusión, beta

Estamos de enhorabuena. De un tiempo a esta parte en [Spanish Language](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/) estamos experimentando un crecimiento progresivo y constante.

A las excelentes contribuciones de [guifa](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/4182/guifa), [Rodrigo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/6915/rodrigo), [Diego](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/5481/diego), [Gorpik](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/1768/gorpik), [guillem](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/1899/guillem) y tantos otros, de un tiempo a esta parte le hemos añadido el gran trabajo de [DGaleano](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/11102/dgaleano), las detalladísimas respuestas de [Yay](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/11511/yay) y a [Carlos Alejo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/12637/carlos-alejo).

Tras poner algunas recompensas, hemos podido también "limpiar" la lista de preguntas sin contestar hasta poder ver ahora algo tan bonito como un 0 -pocas veces un cero sentó tan bien, jeje-:

[image]

Esto nos ha llevado a figurar normalmente en primera posición en la [clasificación de sitios por tanto por ciento de preguntas contestadas](http://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#percentanswered):

[image]

Además, esta efervescencia en el sitio se refleja en la [actividad del sitio semana por semana](http://data.stackexchange.com/spanish/query/161411/site-activity-and-votegraph#graph) (indicando 150 semanas):

[image]

Estamos lejos aún de los números iniciales (mismo enlace que arriba, indicando 360 semanas):

[image]

Vemos más actividad en cuanto a votos y comentarios, si bien es verdad que el número de preguntas y respuestas está algo estancado. Véase el gráfico de [actividad del sitio semana por semana - solamente preguntas, respuestas y respuestas aceptadas](http://data.stackexchange.com/spanish/query/506560/site-activity-and-votegraph-questions-answers-and-accepted) (indicando 150 semanas):

[image]

E históricamente (mismo enlace que arriba, indicando 360 semanas):

[image]

Creo que más o menos hemos visto cómo hacer que una pregunta del sitio aparezca en "[Hot Network Questions](http://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot)" y estas consiguen [su objetivo](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/219922/209901): conseguimos nuevos usuarios y, de vez en cuando, se quedan.

Hace tiempo que estamos en Beta (véase [The Real Essential Questions of Every Beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/223674/209901)) y [los números](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/14456/spanish-language) son aún bajos para optar a "graduar" el sitio: necesitamos mejorar el número de preguntas diarias (estamos en alrededor de 3, cuando se necesitan unas 10; tenemos pocas respuestas por pregunta).

Así que esto me hace pensar: ¿estáis contentos con el sitio? ¿qué creéis que deberíamos hacer para seguir en esta senda? ¿cómo podríamos conseguir más gente y bullicio?

Por lo pronto, recordad que podéis compartir enlaces apretando en el botoncito `share` que hay debajo de cada pregunta y respuesta. Esto os puede incluso dar [una medalla](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/badges/59/announcer). Viendo las pocas veces que se ha otorgado da que pensar que o bien la fábrica de bronce está estropeada o bien no la estamos forzando demasiado : )

Comment: Yo compartí un enlace y conseguí que Pérez-Reverte nos visitara, ¿no dan medalla por eso? ¿No? ¿Calidad mejor que cantidad? :-)

Comment: Muy agradecido por la mención. :-)

Answer (score 7):

Un par de opiniones genéricas sobre los sitios en beta:

1. Por las normas de los sitios de Stack Exchange, votar una pregunta otorga +5 puntos, mientras que responderla otorga +10 y otros +15 si te la aceptan. Como los sitios están gamificados, es normal que algunos olviden un poco la razón de existir del sitio y se centren en el juego. Y como los sitios dan más puntos a los que responden que a los que preguntan, veo lógico que esa gente se quede un poco parada en el tema de las preguntas y se dediquen a responder todo lo que puedan. Es cierto que hay medallas por preguntar, pero las medallas no dan puntos. Por tanto, ¿no sería lógico que los sitios en beta otorguen más puntos a los que preguntan? Esto sería temporal, para animar a la gente a preguntar, y cuando el sitio salga de beta porque ya haya cogido rodaje, se volvería al sistema de puntos estándar.
2. Stack Exchange tiene sus normas, las cuales han sido estudiadas a lo largo de los años y las encuentro lógicas. Sin embargo, tal vez los sitios en beta deban relajar un poco las normas. Por ejemplo, acabo de hacer una pregunta sobre el uso de "sangrar" en impresión. Estoy seguro de que buscando un poco podría haber encontrado la información que busco, pero entonces no habría hecho la pregunta. Estoy intentando contribuir en lo que puedo, cada vez que se me ocurre una posible pregunta la apunto y la voy haciendo, para así contribuir a las estadísticas. Lo que tal vez deberíamos relajar, al menos (repito) durante la fase beta, es el echarnos encima de la gente que haga preguntas incompletas o ligeramente off-topic y votarle negativo, porque así les asustamos e impedimos que hagan más preguntas. Un poco de mano izquierda no nos vendría mal, y me incluyo en esta reflexión.

Sobre lo de compartir enlaces, por supuesto, si alguien suele usar los foros de WordReference y similares, puede ser un buen sitio para ir compartiendo enlaces si alguien ve que hacen alguna pregunta que ya hayamos respondido, por ejemplo.

Comment: ¡Gracias por tus interesantes aportes! Sobre 1. veo que lo propuso el fundador de [se] en [Should the weight of question upvotes be reduced?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/42769/209901). Podría proponerse subirlo para la fase Beta, pero lo veo complicado, pues ciertamente no hay demasiado debate al respecto. Al fin y al cabo, responder _bien_ es más complicado que preguntar bien, pues suele requerir de más tiempo y esfuerzo. (sigo...)

Comment: Como dijo Diego en [What about adding general questions for reference?](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/a/2464/1674), _if I get too cynical I could say that for a good percentage of the questions someone is just letting someone else do their googling for them_.

Comment: Sobre 2. creo que en la fase de Public Beta es importante definir con mucha claridad qué es bueno, qué aceptable y qué se sale del ámbito del sitio. Una vez [creada una tendencia](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/a/378/1674) es muy difícil revertirla, por lo que en este preciso momento se tiene que promocionar la calidad por encima de la cantidad. Eso sí, creo que es genial que hagas preguntas como la que hiciste, pues ayudan a avivar el sitio y generan buenas respuestas. De hecho, esto mismo pretendo yo con muchas de mis preguntas -"buscar en voz alta"-.

Comment: @fedorqui Como comentaba, comprendo perfectamente las reglas y las apruebo. Sin embargo, sitios como SL difieren de SO en que en este último una respuesta te puede sacar tu trabajo adelante. En SL muchas de las preguntas son por pura curiosidad. Veo una diferencia en la finalidad de ambos sitios. Además, en SO tienen un problema de exceso de preguntas, mientras que aquí pasa todo lo contrario. Por eso opino que las reglas deberían modificarse aunque sea levemente para sacar el sitio adelante. En todo caso, entiendo lo de las tendencias, y me apunto lo de votar más.

Comment: @fedorqui Sobre las normas, me refería a relajarlas, no a darles la vuelta. Por ejemplo, si una pregunta es duda acerca de si es off-topic o no, pues aceptarla. Obviamente, si es completamente off-topic o de mal gusto o lo que sea, pues se elimina. Se trataría simplemente de, si vas a dudar, no lo hagas.

Comment: Sí, estoy de acuerdo. Las preguntas de _necesidad_ suelen venir a través de nuevos usuarios. En el caso de los que llevamos más tiempo por aquí y/o tenemos el castellano como lengua materna, sí las veo como curiosidad. De todos modos, y no sé si coincidirás conmigo, conseguir reputación y encaramarse en la parte alta de la clasificación aquí es relativamente fácil. Por ello, creo que es más interesante _ludificar_ las medallas como Curious, Inquisitive, Socratic o las que se consiguen por número de visitas a una pregunta.

Comment: Sobre las normas, creo que actualmente sí se tiene cierta manga ancha: muchas respuestas cortitas que en [so] se eliminarían aquí suelen mantenerse, así como algunas otras que podrían cerrarse por no mantener el formato Q&A en exceso. Pero esa es mi opinión y lo mismo me estoy dejando casos en el tintero. Creo que es fundamental generar cierta discusión debajo de dichas preguntas para ver si todo el mundo está relativamente alineado al respecto.

Comment: @fedorqui me ha encantado el uso de _ludificar_ en vez de _gamificar_. Sí que es cierto que en sitios pequeños es más sencillo obtener puntos, pero al mismo tiempo es más complicado obtener según qué medallas al no haber mucha gente que vote. En todo caso, entiendo que las preguntas se potencien mediante medallas más que con puntos. Pero si estamos de acuerdo y no hacemos ningún cambio, ¿cómo resolvemos la pregunta original?

Comment: [Ludificar mejor que gamificar, dijo Fundéu](http://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/ludificacion-mejor-que-gamificacion-como-traduccion-de-gamification-1390/), jeje :) Pues yo creo que la clave está en agitar esto un poco y que no sea tan endogámico: somos pocos preguntando y contestando. Creo que si conseguimos algún Carlos Alejo más cada poco tiempo esto puede crecer exponencialmente. Por tanto: pidamos a la gente que vote más y que intente vincular a otras personas. Se me ocurrió hablar con Fundéu y el RAE para ver si querrían colaborar con este sitio, por ejemplo.

Comment: Uhms, he estado sacando el gráfico que representa solamente preguntas y respuestas por semana y ha rebajado mi emoción: estamos algo mejor, pero no se ve tanta mejora en estos dos campos. Donde sí hay es en el número de votos y comentarios. He actualizado la pregunta con estos detalles.

Answer (score 3):

¡Esto sigue creciendo!

Por primera vez (que yo haya visto) hemos cruzado el umbral de 5 preguntas por día de media (recordemos que este numerito cuenta las dos últimas semanas).

> [image]

29 octubre 2017: 7 preguntas por día.

[image]

Comment: Exacto, este número es la media de las dos últimas semanas, así que ¡hay que mantener el ritmo! Y sobre todo escribir más respuestas por pregunta para cambiar el "okay" por un "excellent", que lo tenemos ahí a tiro.

Comment: ¡Así sea! Lo que ahora se nos está yendo de las manos es el número de [preguntas sin respuestas](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/unanswered) jaja.

Comment: Creo que llegó a 7.1 pero ya está bajando otra vez

Comment: ¿Dónde se pueden ver esas infografías? ¿O están restringidas?

Comment: @karloswitt en https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/14456/spanish-language Cuando el sitio [salió de Beta](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3128/1674) se paró el cronómetro y quedó una foto fija allí. En cualquier caso, en https://stackexchange.com/sites puedes ver todos los sitios y una serie de métricas actualizadas constantemente: preguntas / respuestas / % respondidas / usuarios / visitas diarias / preguntas diarias / edad del sitio.

Answer (score 2):

Creo que es importante identificar las diferentes razones detrás de las preguntas que se realizan para así lograr formular una estrategia para promover y motivar la participación en el sitio.

Así bien, es necesario establecer objetivos claros para poder alcanzarlos. Esto permite un análisis más cuantitativo de las diferentes medidas que se lleven a cabo para fomentar el crecimiento del sitio.

Por ejemplo, viendo los perfiles de muchos de los miembros se puede notar que buena parte de ellos son personas que trabajan en el área de informática, lo que ha hecho que preguntas relativas a cómo traducir conceptos informáticos se mantegan activas y populares.

Otra gran parte de la población es aquella en la que el español no es su lengua madre y tiene curiosidad de cómo traducir frases al español. Este tipo de preguntas son las más vistas, si observan el número de vistas en la página que lista las preguntas notarán que aquellas preguntas que se realizan en inglés cuentan con el mayor número de visitas.

Para muestra de esto veamos las siguientes preguntas:

- [How prevalent is the phrase “qué padre”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/92/how-prevalent-is-the-phrase-qu%C3%A9-padre) 21, 000 vistas
- [Why is the 'b' and 'v' pronunciation inconsistent?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/12890/why-is-the-b-and-v-pronunciation-inconsistent) 15, 000 vistas
- [Spanish for “breasts” [closed]](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/10442/spanish-for-breasts) 13, 000 vistas
- [Etymologically, why do “ser” and “estar” exist? / Etimológicamente, ¿por qué existen “ser” y “estar”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/18440/etymologically-why-do-ser-and-estar-exist-etimol%C3%B3gicamente-por-qu%C3%A9-exi) 3, 000 vistas
- [How to say “because!” in Spanish?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/19083/how-to-say-because-in-spanish) 2, 500 vistas

Es probable que las siguientes preguntas tendrían más vistas si se hubieran hecho en inglés:

- [¿Qué término se usa en español para “Game Changer”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/19109/qu%C3%A9-t%C3%A9rmino-se-usa-en-espa%C3%B1ol-para-game-changer)
- [¿Cómo traducir “Sidekick”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/19075/c%C3%B3mo-traducir-sidekick)
- [¿Qué es una “bala de plata”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/18968/qu%C3%A9-es-una-bala-de-plata)

Esto no significa que todas las preguntas deberían hacerse en inglés, después de todo este es un sitio dedicado para el lenguaje español. Es sólo una reflexión en cuanto a los componentes de la población y qué los atrae al sitio. Las preguntas en "*hot network questions*" atraen a más personas si se encuentran en inglés.

Lo cual lleva al siguiente punto, relacionado a lo que [Carlos Alejo](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/users/12637/carlos-alejo) menciona en cuanto a las reglas: Hay varias preguntas que se nota que nuevos miembros vienen para tratar de obtener una traducción que no tiene sentido cuando usan google translate. He aquí un ejemplo: [How do I translate the following [closed]](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/19192/how-do-i-translate-the-following). Y esto nos lleva de vuelta al punto de los objetivos del sitio, ¿qué se desea hacer con este tipo de preguntas? ¿Se relajan las reglas temporalmente? ¿Si se relajan las reglas no se sienta un precedente al que nuevos miembros pueden aducir?

Solamente hoy, hay algunas incidencias en las que hay respuestas que no son claras y han estado en espera de moderación por ser consideradas de [baja calidad](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/19234/13575), cuando existen respuestas en [el pasado](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/18726/13575) que cuentan con la misma calidad. Esto puede afectar la moral de nuevos miembros.

Continuando con el tema de traducción, he notado que aquellas respuestas que cuentan con más información relacionada a traducciones regionales son populares, también. Aparte, tal vez los comentarios en español son un poco excluyentes para aquellos miembros que no hablan tan bien el idioma, ya que pueden sentir que se habla "*detrás de sus espaldas*".

Finalmente, en cuanto la población cuya lengua materna es el español, recordemos lo que consolidó nuestro lenguaje: La literatura. El español se consolidó bajo la obra literaria del Quijote, e incluso existe la anécdota que la Real Academia Española se fundó con el objetivo que "*las siguientes generaciones pudieran apreciar la obra de Cervantes*".

Esto implica que es válido hacer preguntas literarias, el cómo expresar cosas de manera figurativa, cómo se escribiría cierto pasaje en español moderno, cuál es la intención de cierto autor en una obra en particular (lo que busca comunicar). Ese fomento podría promover la lectura de ciertas obras e incluso motivar a aquellos que están aprendiendo el español a acercarse al maravilloso mundo de la literatura española, que es algo de lo que no están conscientes que se están perdiendo.

Para concluir, si el objetivo del sitio es incentivar a los miembros del área de informática, las estrategias deberían estar más enfocadas a promover ese tipo de preguntas y discusiones relevantes al crecimiento del lenguaje español hacia términos tecnológicos. Si el objetivo del sitio es incentivar a los miembros que hablan inglés y buscan traducciones, las estrategias deben adecuarse más a promover preguntas relacionadas a traducciones de ciertas frases (e incluso aquellas que no se pueden traducir en google translate). Y si el objetivo del sitio es atraer a más personas que hablan primariamente el español, las estrategias deben centrarse en lo que hace al español tan rico, es decir su literatura, las variantes entre diferentes regiones, etc.

Comment: Al hilo de lo que comentaste, preguntas como esta pueden ser fantásticas  para la sección _preguntas literarias_: [Significado de “sinrazón” en “Don Quijote”](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/19279/1674)

Answer (score 1):

Creo que una forma de augmentar la actividad del sitio sobre todo con hablantes de castellano, que como bien decía Carlos tenemos más difícil el hacer preguntas que vayan mas allá de la curiosidad, sería sacrificar un poco el formato Q&A por tener debates.

No soy un usuario veterano de Stack Exchange por lo que quizá sea ir contra la naturaleza de la network y correríamos el riesgo de ver como el sitio se convierte en otro foro más que en un sitio de Q&A.

También es cierto que podemos ver en otras comunidades ([WorldBuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/) por ejemplo) que las preguntas con más votos y participación son de respuesta abierta.

Quizá se pueda encontrar un término medio, algún tipo de regulación, que permita la existencia de debates sin permitir que estos dominen el sitio por completo.

Comment: Yo no soy partidario de que el objetivo principal de una pregunta determinada sea abrir un debate. Sí creo que sería interesante utilizar Meta para esto en algún caso. Al fin y al cabo, lo bueno de [se] es que permite crear un banco de conocimiento, contrariamente a otras comunidades que buscan debate, etc. Afinemos, de todos modos, la sugerencia para ver si hay algo que se podría cambiar. Creo que actualmente las preguntas generan muy interesantes comentarios que cumplen buena parte de esta función, pero manteniendo el debate como algo secundario, no como pregunta en sí.

Comment: Nótese que tenemos cierta manga ancha con preguntas algo genéricas y que esto también ha provocado que muchas se pueblen de innumerables respuestas que acaban generando más ruido que otra cosa (de ahí que [propusiera](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/q/2483/1674) juntarlo en respuestas community wiki)

Comment: Añado (y paro ya): los refrances y los extranjerismos son una fuenta casi inagotable de preguntas para los que somos hispanohablantes. Por ejemplo, tirar del hilo de esta noticia daría para una decena de preguntas: [A ver quién traduce esto (2): 14 expresiones que solo entendemos los españoles](http://elpais.com/elpais/2016/07/05/icon/1467712032_502926.html)

Answer (score 1):

Actualización a 28 de septiembre:

- El sitio ha pasado de 3 a **3,6 preguntas al día**. Vamos por buen camino, pero tenemos que llegar hasta 5.
- Recibimos una media de **2,4 respuestas por pregunta**. Está casi bien, hay que llegar a 2,5, así que deberíamos proponernos tener al menos 3 respuestas por pregunta de aquí en adelante para ir subiendo la media.
- No se ve una tendencia clara al alza en cuanto al número de publicaciones (preguntas o respuestas) o al número de votos, pero sí en cuanto al tráfico recibido, sobre todo a partir de principios de agosto:

[image: Gráfica de los últimos meses]

- Para que lo veáis con más claridad, aquí va la gráfica desde el principio de los tiempos, veréis un repunte al alza en el extremo derecho correspondiente a los últimos dos meses:

[image: Gráfica global]

Comment: ¡Fantástico! Hay que empezar a repartir más medallas [Announcer](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/badges/59/announcer) a quien comparta contenido de aquí para generar aún más tráfico : )

Comment: Por cierto, un día detecté un pico que nos situó en las 5 preguntas de media ---> http://i.stack.imgur.com/BpQa8.png

Comment: @fedorqui al respecto de lo de compartir contenido... [¿Cuáles son los mejores sitios para compartir enlaces y atraer tráfico?](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/q/2509/12637)

Comment: Ya que estamos, podemos adoptar una pregunta/respuestas del tipo  [Resources for learning Japanese](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/q/756/18078). No sé si expandir [What are some good online resources we can use?](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/q/74/1674) o crear una nueva directamente. ¿Qué te parece?

Comment: @fedorqui necesitaríamos convertir en _community wiki_ una pregunta y una respuesta de dos usuarios diferentes. Si eso no se puede hacer, mejor crear una pregunta nueva directamente en dicho modo, con respuestas _community_ ya clasificadas por categorías, y darle promoción.

Comment: Lo de convertir en _community wiki_ no es problema: con las herramientas que nos dan a los moderadores lo hacemos en un solo clic. Miro la pregunta original y su alcance (scope?) es _What publicly-available resources ought I consult when asking or answering questions here?_. No sé si la pervertiría demasiado ampliarla a _What publicly-available resources ought I consult when learning Spanish?_.

Comment: @fedorqui son cosas diferentes, diría yo. Una cosa es dar a la gente recursos para aprender español, como menciona la pregunta sobre aprender japonés (aquí sería _Resources for learning Spanish_), y otra cosa es recursos que hay que consultar para preguntar y responder. Es decir, recursos que consideramos como autoridades (lo típico de que un texto de la Wikipedia no tiene credibilidad, pero lo que dice la RAE sí).

Comment: Empecemos pues :) [Resources for learning Spanish](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/q/2514/1674).

Comment: Lo que sí deberé cambiar es el enlace de la "off-topic  reason", que actualmente es: _Questions seeking learning resources are off-topic here, but see: [What are some good online resources we can use?](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/74/what-are-some-good-online-resources-we-can-use)_. En cuanto esa pregunta crezca un poco, lo hago.

Comment: [¡Llegamos a 5 preguntas/día!](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/14456/spanish-language).

Comment: @fedorqui mola, pero aún pone "needs work", habrá que llegar a 5,1 para que ponga "okay". :-) ¡Vamos a ello! Que la verdad es que sí se está notando que últimamente hay más preguntas en el sitio...

Comment: Pues por primera vez, [¡lo conseguimos!](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/a/2537/1674)