# Juegos y otros en Spanish Language

Tags: discusión

Estaba yo pensando que, ya que tenemos un foro donde hacer preguntas y respuestas sobre el idioma español, y tal vez un poco por [darle más juego al sitio](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2490/12637) y atraer más atención, ¿sería posible ampliar un poco el rango de preguntas para incluir juegos, adivinanzas y demás?

La idea parte un poco de ver cómo en Stack Exchange hay sitios específicos para esto, pero siempre en idioma inglés. Por ejemplo, [Puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/). Y desde luego, las adivinanzas y demás son una forma muy buena de aprender el idioma. Por lo que no veo descabellado el que quien quiera inventarse una adivinanza que verse sobre alguna palabra del español la pueda hacer. Y quien dice adivinanzas dice otro tipo de juegos, como el de buscar una palabra que concuerde con una definición y que comience por tres letras dadas (como en [Saber y ganar](http://www.rtve.es/alacarta/videos/saber-y-ganar/), siempre que la gente no salga corriendo a usar el [DIRAE](http://dirae.es/)). La imaginación sería el límite.

Así pues, la pregunta sería si podríamos ampliar el ámbito de preguntas del sitio a este tipo de juegos, dándoles una etiqueta dada (por ejemplo "adivinanzas" o "juegos") para que la gente pueda marcar las categorías como favoritas, y siempre que versen sobre el español y fomenten su aprendizaje. A fin de cuentas, serían preguntas que no admitirían debate ya que tendrían respuestas concretas (sólo que estarían previamente acordadas por el mismo que pregunta).

Lo único que temo es el riesgo de que este tipo de preguntas se convierta en la mayoría, pero si vemos que eso pasa siempre podemos solicitar abrir un nuevo sitio en Stack Exchange para separar ambos temas. Seguramente al principio y con la novedad pueda suceder, se trataría de ver cómo evoluciona el tema a medio plazo.

Espero vuestras opiniones.

Comment: ¡Interesante! Hace unos días descubrí los [Weekly challenges](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240634/209901) y me parecieron muy buena idea. No es lo mismo que lo que propones, pero sí una idea que ya está implementada en la comunidad actualmente. El alcance de nuestro sitio ahora mismo no permitiría preguntas del tipo de Puzzling y no sé si abrirlo a ellas nos daría más disgustos que beneficios (usuarios regulares que lo dejaran por la pérdida de rigor en favor de algo más lúdico). Pero veamos qué piensa la gente...

Comment: @fedorqui pues parece que la gente no piensa gran cosa (del tema)... :-D

Comment: Esto es un páramo :/ Lo mismo es cuestión de hacer política de hechos consumados: lánzate y a ver qúe tal sale ;-) ¿Y empezando en Meta?

Comment: @fedorqui ¿Empezando en Meta? ¿A qué te refieres?

Comment: A plantear una de estas preguntas/juego en Meta, en lugar del sitio principal.

Comment: @fedorqui si queremos ver la reacción de la gente, sería interesante hacerlo en el sitio principal, dado que por aquí la gente pasa de higos a brevas (me incluyo, lo reconozco). En todo caso, primero tendría que pensar la pregunta/juego, a ver qué se me ocurre...

Comment: A mí así en genérico me cuesta verlo en el sitio principal, más que nada porque se sale completamente del tipo de preguntas que tenemos actualmente. Plantea un esquema de pregunta y lo revisamos entre todos por aquí, para ver si encajaría.

Comment: @fedorqui se me está ocurriendo ahora mismo una especie de "búsqueda del tesoro". No serían preguntas sencillas de plantear, por lo que no corremos el riesgo de que abunden en el sitio. Y de paso enseñamos a la gente los recursos disponibles: buscar la definición de la palabra tal en la primera edición del DRAE en la que apareció la palabra, y coger la palabra tal de la definición. Lo mismo con el CORDE, el CREA, y que al final la gente monte una frase con las pistas que será la respuesta a la pregunta. Pero tengo que darle algunas vueltas.

Comment: ¿Aplica para esta etiqueta propuesta el "translation golf" que han venido "jugando"? . BTW No estoy interesado en juegos en este sitio. (pero que juegue el que quiera, tampoco me opongo)

Comment: @DGaleano todas las ediciones del translation-golf se han etiquetado como "juego", si a eso te refieres, sí.

Answer (score 1):

Me parece buena idea hacer juegos para incitar la participación en el sitio. Se me ocurría hacer una especie de citar textos de determinada bibliografía, y usuarios tendrían que adivinar el autor, o la obra o el libro al que pertenece la frase. No se bien si funcionaría o como lo haría, pero es una idea :).

Comment: ¡Suena bien! Debería "codificarse" de alguna forma para que no fuera fácil de encontrar por Google. ¿Cómo crees que podríamos dificultarlo manteniendo el entretenimiento?