# ¡Cumplimos 5 años en beta!

Tags: discusión

Mirando en la página de estadísticas de [Spanish Language en Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/14456/spanish-language) me di cuenta de que... **¡estos días se cumplen cinco años de la entrada del sitio en beta!**

Por lo que veo la cosa fue así:

- El 29 de abril de 2011 empezó la fase de "commitment" (recabar apoyos para crear la página)
- El 15 de noviembre de 2011 empezó la beta privada.
- Una semana después, el 22 de noviembre, empezó la beta pública.

Así que permitidme que haga un listado de lo que veo que ocurre últimamente, para impulsar un debate de alegría por lo conseguido y mejora para seguir creciendo.

## Cosas buenas

- Últimamente estamos teniendo picos importantes de preguntas:

  - semana del 25 de julio → 42 preguntas
  - semana del 17 de octubre → 41 preguntas
  - semana del 24 de octubre → 39 preguntas
- Hace poco llegamos finalmente a las 5 preguntas diarias de media en las dos últimas dos semanas. Lo mantuvimos unos cuantos días.

> [image]

- Desde marzo, cada semana tenemos al menos 15 preguntas (más de dos diarias).

[image]

- El número de ediciones está disparado.
- Votamos cada vez más. Parece que se ha acabado eso de que [se vota poco en este sitio](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2446/1674).

[image]

- Cada vez tenemos más visitas

[image]

## Cosas no tan buenas

- **Seguimos siendo pocos y la gente se acaba yendo al cabo del tiempo**. A lo largo de la historia de este sitio han ido pasando personas muy activas que al cabo del tiempo han dejado de entrar. Por ejemplo, si revisáis la lista de [usuarios con más reputación por año](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/163/year/spanish) y vais cambiando el año, veréis caras diferentes cada vez.
  [Diego](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/5481/diego), [Gonzalo Medina](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/157/gonzalo-medina), [Alfredo Osorio](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/85/alfredo-osorio) o [leonbloy](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/61/leonbloy) son solo algunos de los usuarios que han dejado gran cantidad de publicaciones excelentes en el sitio y que ahora no tenemos la suerte de ver con tanta frecuencia.
- **Las preguntas suelen venir a cuentagotas** y o bien de personas nuevas o bien de un par de usuarios habituales. ¿Seguro que no tenéis dudas sobre la lengua? :)
- **El número de preguntas sin respuesta sigue creciendo** (ahora mismo 16) y quede lejos [el día en que conseguimos dejarlo a 0](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2490/1674). Las recompensas han espoleado la curiosidad de la gente durante mucho tiempo y han aportado fantásticas respuestas. Sin embargo, de un tiempo a esta parte muchas de estas recompensas se terminan sin entregar.
- **Sigue habiendo pocas respuestas por pregunta**. Una de las estadísticas de Area51 dice que se recomienda que cada pregunta tenga al menos 2,5 respuestas. Estamos en 2,4 desde hace siglos.

## ¿Qué tenemos por delante?

- ¿Qué hay que hacer para que la gente siga entrando? ¿Qué veis que falla aquí para que los usuarios regulares dejen de entrar?
- ¿Cómo conseguimos más preguntas? ¿Y si hiciéramos [Weekly Challenges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240634/209901) como en otros sitios? Es decir, ludificar la creación de preguntas tal y como Carlos Alejo también comentó en [Juegos y otros en Spanish Language](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2522/1674).
- ¿Cómo conseguimos más respuestas por pregunta?
- ¿Cómo conseguimos que casi todas las preguntas tengan respuesta?
- [Pongamos algo de orden en las etiquetas](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2495/1674) para poder encontrar mejor lo que buscamos.
- [Definamos preguntas/respuestas canónicas](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2505/1674) para dejarlas niqueladas y que sirvan de referencia.
- Hay muchos comentarios muy valiosos. Recordad que los [comentarios son elementos de segunda](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19757/209901) categoría aquí, por lo que si queremos que persista el conocimiento es recomendable publicar respuestas si tenemos algo importante a explicar. Si nos da vergüenza publicar una respuesta algo corta (pero útil), siempre la podemos marcar como Wiki para incentivar que otras personas la mejoren.
- ¿Y si galardonáramos las mejores respuestas dadas en un tiempo determinado? En Movies & TV [lo hacen](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2340/4078) y parece bonito.

**¿Qué más se te ocurre?** ¿Qué es lo que te hace entrar en este sitio y qué crees que te haría entrar aún más? ¿Y qué te incomoda hasta el punto de pensar en no entrar más?

## Pero recordemos: enhorabuena a todos por haber llegado hasta aquí. ¡Por muchos años más!

Comment: Y justo hoy 8 de mayo de 2017... ¡cumplimos 2000 días en beta!

Answer (score 2):

Llevo unos días preguntándome si realmente es tan malo no tener un 100% de preguntas sin responder. Sin ir más lejos, el foro que dio origen a todo esto, Stack Overflow, tiene un 72% de preguntas respondidas. Es decir, que con el paso del tiempo es normal que empiecen a aparecer preguntas sin responder.

Los motivos que pueden causar esto son:

- Se hacen preguntas complicadas que requieren grandes conocimientos, o conocimientos muy particulares que muy poca gente en el foro posee. Recordemos que no todo se encuentra en Internet, y algunas de nuestras preguntas pueden suponer consultas a textos especializados de difícil acceso. Puede que incluso directamente no se puedan responder, o que hagamos preguntas dignas de tesis doctorales en filología.
- Se hacen preguntas que ya se han respondido antes, o que directamente la gente del foro considera que se pueden solucionar con una simple búsqueda.
- Se hacen preguntas que no están bien formuladas, lo que dificulta una respuesta.
- Se hacen preguntas sencillas que se responden en los comentarios.

Soluciones:

- Para el primer caso, como no tratemos de publicitar el foro en las escuelas de filología, lo llevamos claro. Me pregunto si no será que la gente de letras usa menos Internet. El otro día conocí a un abogado que nos reconoció que Internet lo usaba entre poco y nada, como mucho un poco de correo electrónico, el "guasá" y para de contar. ¿Realmente existe una brecha así? ¿La gente que tiene el conocimiento de letras que necesitamos accede menos a Internet que la gente de ciencias?
- Para el segundo caso, necesitamos que las nuevas incorporaciones al foro se animen a responder, o que la gente use más el sistema de marcar las preguntas como duplicadas.
- Para el tercer caso, a veces pasa que la gente hace una pregunta y luego se desentiende de ella, o no sabe cómo mejorarla. En este segundo caso se intenta dirigir al nuevo hacia la forma correcta de preguntar, y en el primero habrá que eliminar la pregunta.
- Para el último caso, se debe animar a escribir respuestas, aunque ello implique a veces que esta sea corta (puede que no necesite muchas explicaciones, pero no por ello deja de ser una respuesta válida).

En todo caso, no tener un 100% de respuestas no creo que sea malo. De hecho, puede que un día empiece a llegar al foro gente con los conocimientos adecuados (mejorando lo presente) y comience a dar respuesta a las preguntas que se van quedando sin. Mientras tanto, los que estamos hacemos lo que podemos.

Con respecto al número de preguntas por respuesta: ya no estamos en 2.4, sino en 2.3. Hemos bajado, sí, pero también me pregunto si por las características peculiares de nuestro sitio no será normal. Por ejemplo, el otro día pregunté el antónimo de "cacofonía". Un usuario dijo que era "eufonía" y listo, pregunta respondida. Obviamente no todas las preguntas son así, pero tal vez no sea un aspecto demasiado importante. Lo que me resulta más curioso es que tenemos más de 8000 usuarios (muchos más de los que se espera de una "beta" saludable), y seguimos teniendo los problemas de pocas preguntas y usuarios que se acaban aburriendo. Este es el aspecto que deberíamos mejorar. Yo propondría hacer algo para que los nuevos tengan incentivos, ponerles las cosas fáciles al principio, pasarles la mano, animarles a hacer más preguntas, al menos mientras tengan menos de 100 puntos (contando el bonus de asociación: si lo tienen es porque ya saben cómo preguntar en otros foros). Y para los que llevamos ya un tiempo, pues abrir la puerta a preguntas con juegos, o lo de los retos semanales que comentabas. Últimamente estaba pensando en preguntas que ludifiquen el aprendizaje del uso de herramientas como el CORDE, el NTTLE, etc.

Comment: Muy inspiradora tu reflexión. Hace poco leí en [Travel](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/q/3755/6997), donde también están intentando llegar al 100%: _Answering as many as possible is obviously good, but sometimes questions legitimately don't have answers yet because they're challenging, interesting questions about routes or situations few people have taken yet - better to leave these for adventurous souls to answer well when possible than fill them with fluff or close them spuriously, surely? If we had the most answered questions of any site, I'd worry our pool of questions was too easy_

Comment: Yo abogaría por, al menos, intentar ir dejando contestadas las preguntas "fáciles", aunque sea moviendo los comentarios a la zona de respuestas. Por el contrario, las "difíciles" está bien que aparezcan sin contestar hasta que alguien con suficiente conocimiente les pueda hincar el diente. Y sí, eso pasa por conseguir gente nueva con conocimientos --¿y si hiciéramos carteles? tengo acceso a una facultad de filología :)

Comment: En cuanto al número de usuarios, [395 avid users](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/14456/spanish-language) es engañoso. Yo más bien veo grupos de personas que aparecen por aquí durante un tiempo y luego desaparecen, más que un grupo que se está haciendo cada vez más grande. Lo bueno es que siempre hay "recambios", lo malo es que el número absoluto en un momento dado sigue bastante estancado.

Comment: @fedorqui pues mira, no había leído el foro de Travel, pero más o menos veo que llegan a la misma conclusión. Y sobre lo otro, pues no te creas que no es mala idea tirar del mundo analógico de vez en cuando. Yo podría hacer lo propio en la Instituto de Idiomas de la Universidad de Sevilla, que dan clases de español para extranjeros.

Comment: @fedorqui lo del número usuarios "ávidos", claro, se refiere a los usuarios con más de 200 de reputación, que no quiere decir que se pasen por aquí regularmente. Y sobre lo de las preguntas sin responder, yo agradezco los cuatro "bounties" que hay ahora mismo en cuatro preguntas mías, pero tengo mis dudas de que vayan a ser efectivos si nadie sabe responderlas. En todo caso, por probar nada se pierde (bueno, sí, la recompensa en sí si nadie responde).

Comment: Sí, lo de "ávidos" no es muy representativo: 200 puntos son relativamente fáciles de conseguir y lo mismo fue hace cuatro años, por lo que a efectos prácticos no son usuarios del sitio. En cuanto a las recompensas, en Travel hay un moderador que va abriendo bounties y los cancela si no ha podido entregarlos. Así, va subiendo cada vez a 50, 100, 150... y con ello han conseguido grandes éxitos. No creo que sea correcto de todos modos, pues usa herramientas de moderador para cuestiones que no deberían.

Comment: @fedorqui ¿el fin no justifica los medios? :-) Por cierto, te planteo una cosa. Hay ahora mismo 16 preguntas que están con 0 respuestas. 11 son mías. ¿Qué debería hacer? ¿Dejar de preguntar para poder aumentar el porcentaje de preguntas sin responder? ¿O seguir preguntando para poder tener más preguntas por día?

Comment: Haz lo que te dé más placer: tenerte en este sitio es un lujazo así que haz lo que te pida el cuerpo sin tener en cuenta estadísticas ni métricas. Si te surgen dudas, pregunta; si te surgen respuestas a lo preguntado, contesta. No estamos ni cerca de graduar el sitio ni cerca de conseguir nada concreto, por lo que no hace falta táctica sino contenido interesante como el que siempre presentan tus preguntas.

Comment: @fedorqui efectivamente. Lo importante no son las métricas, sino el que los que estemos aquí aprendamos y nos lo pasemos bien por el camino. :-)

Comment: Y reconozco que yo mismo me dejé arrastrar por la métrica en bastantes ocasiones, especialmente la de % de preguntas contestadas. A esta respuesta pongo por testigo que intentaré no prestarle tanta atención.

Answer (score 1):

Of the things which you mention in your *Cosas no tan buenas* it is the first one which is the most worrying for the future of the site because if there are only a few very active users then if they decide to go on a long holiday, fall ill, lose interest, ... then the site will collapse.

The other things are to some extent just responses to the arbitrary criteria set by the site management. It would be easy to turn more comments into answers if that was needed as some of them are partial answers and as long as nobody objects they could be used as answers.

Apologies that this is in English but I would not be sure of getting the right tone in Spanish. Feel free to comment in Spanish though, reading is less of a problem.

Comment: Oh do not apologize at all. In fact I should apologize for just writing the post in Spanish. If I get the time I will translate all that I can.

Comment: And yes, I agree this is the most worrying issue. See for example the last days, where regular askers did not post as much and the site looks a bit idle. Honestly, I don't know what we can do to improve this.

Comment: @fedorqui I think you can assume that anyone who reads Meta reads Spanish. The main site is a different kettle of fish.

Comment: Thanks, mdewey. [Some time ago](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/q/2497/1674) I was asked to write them also in English (see comments there), but I have to admit I also have this feeling that just people fluent in Spanish show up in Meta.

Answer (score 1):

Yo creo que estar o seguir en beta es de hecho algo bueno, y el pasar de beta no es necesariamente algo que vaya a mejorar este *stack*. Al fin y al cabo tenemos ya esta gloriosa infraestructura y si, por una razón o por otra, pasásemos de beta, yo creo que veríamos pocos cambios (la apariencia del sitio y los niveles de reputación para ciertos privilegios, básicamente).

Decía Einstein que todos somos unos genios, pero que si juzgas a un pez por su capacidad para trepar árboles, este se va sentir un fracasado toda su vida. Quizá los requisitos para pasar de beta no funcionan del todo bien a favor de los *stacks* orientados a idiomas (creo que salvo el de Inglés y Japonés, el resto están también en beta...). Quizá nos conviene más preguntarnos qué entendemos por **contenido de calidad** para Spanish.SE y cómo lograrlo.

Cómo ya habéis mencionado, tenemos un número bajo de respuestas por pregunta, pero la mayoría de las respuestas para nuestras preguntas no favorecen varios enfoques (En Stack Overflow por ejemplo, si hago una pregunta sobre programación, es posible que hay varias maneras de conseguir lo que quiero, y puedo votar la más elegante, práctica, simple... Con nuestras preguntas es más difícil dar varias respuestas). Quizá no todos esos criterios para pasar de beta favorecen lo que buscamos en este *stack*.

La mayoría de los asiduos del sitio son (somos) amateurs. Por eso cuando alguien plantea preguntas que no se pueden resolver con una búsqueda rápida o con conocimiento básico o de "nivel aficionado" cuesta mucho que sean respondidas.

Algunos estáis proponiendo preguntas muy interesantes, que pasan del típico ""resolver una duda de gramática / ortografía / tiempos verbales" a "cuál es el origen de la esta expresión" o acerca de curiosidades del lenguaje. Y sé de sobra que muchos podríais responder vuestras propias preguntas fácilmente buscando en google, pero preferís postear por aquí para compartir con la gente, crear contenido y animar a que la gente participe, que me parece genial y es bueno para este sitio. Por otro lado, trataría de evitar caer en lo fácil intentando atraer a más gente a base de hacer preguntas super sencillas o de forma "artificial": por ejemplo, si se me ocurre preguntar qué es una [postverdad](http://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/post-truth-post-verdad-posverdad/), que ha sido nombrada palabra del año. Es una pregunta que se puede responder con una simple búsqueda y aunque el post sumaría a las estadísticas, en cuanto a contenido puede quedar muy flojo

Desde luego creo que votar es importante, porque esas recompensas animan a la gente a querer contribuir más, pero a la larga la gente no se va a quedar por tener un perfil con 25000 puntos y 40 medallas, sino por que le interesa preguntar, leer y discutir acerca del idioma.

Básicamente, creo que si no pasamos de beta (si no tenemos tantas preguntas, o cierto número de usuarios frecuentes) es quizá porque no somos vistos como el recurso de aprendizaje del español o foro de discusión sobre el español que la gente quiere. Yo seguiría centrándome en generar contenido de calidad, como hasta ahora hemos hecho, ayudar a los nuevos de manera amistosa y esperar que cada vez más gente se quede o vuelva, porque encuentra el sitio útil. Poco a poco iremos convirtiéndonos en una referencia y el paso de beta a lo que sea, ya se hará cuando haya una comunidad sólida de usuarios que tengan necesidad de preguntar y otros de participar y responder, más que cuando tengamos PI respuestas por pregunta y 2^n nuevos usuarios al día.

Comment: Muy agudas reflexiones, gracias Diego. El objetivo del sitio es captar talento y eso lleva tiempo. En [so] han conseguido que incluso [el creador de Python](http://stackoverflow.com/users/818274/guido-van-rossum) tenga cuenta, así como innombrables personas importantes del sector ([algún](http://stackoverflow.com/users/95810/alex-martelli) [ejemplo](http://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert)). En nuestro caso, imagina qué gozada sería tener a algún miembro de la RAE. [Sigue]

Comment: ... De ahí que lo de _trataría de evitar caer en lo fácil intentando atraer a más gente a base de hacer preguntas super sencillas o de forma "artificial"_ creo que da en el clavo y me lo aplico a mí mismo, que a veces pregunto un poco para hacer un "ping" a la comunidad. Del mismo modo, creo que sería bueno profundizar en las [preguntas canónicas](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/q/2505/1674) para no andar contestando siempre lo mismo y, además, tener contenido de calidad que se vaya puliendo poco a poco.

Comment: @fedorqui, para clarificar, creo que muchas de tus preguntas tipo "de dónde viene esa expresión" son grandes aportaciones y cómo digo, sé que sueles usarlas para mantener vivo el sitio. No creo que hayamos llegado a hacer preguntas "copy-paste" solo para atraer tráfico o nuevos usuarios, pero quería comentarlo porque alguna vez me había planteado hacerlo yo mismo por esos motivos y luego me dije " si es que un moderador me cerraría la pregunta por falta de esfuerzo". Es más un aviso que una crítica. No creo que el fenómeno se esté dando en el stack, pero no quiero vernos caer en ello.

Comment: De hecho, como gran contribuidor del sitio que eres y ojalá sigas siendo mucho tiempo, sería muy bueno saber detalles sobre cómo ves la comunidad tras tu paréntesis de casi medio año. Vengo pensando en el concepto del _regusto de la comunidad_ para visualizar qué sensación deja en cada usuario. ¿Promovemos actualmente que la gente siga entrando y aportando o, por lo contrario, damos una sensación no del todo satifactoria que hace que la gente se acabe cansando y yendo?

Comment: @fedorqui buena idea. A priori yo diria que el sitio no ha cambiado mucho. Hay algunas caras nuevas y otros parece que no postean desde hace mucho. En cuanto a calidad o numero de preguntas y respuestas, yo diria que andamos mas o menos igual que hace un año, cuando desapareci para explorar ortos planos de existencia... :-) Yo diria que la gente (los asiduos) estan aqui mas por hobby que otra cosa. Pero lo que puedo hacer es esperar un poco mas, ver como funciona ahora el foro, y luego volver a escribir en este hilo u otro con algunas reflexiones.