# Preguntad, preguntad, malditos

Tags: discusión, juegos

### English

Over last days we have been commenting in our chat room [La Tertulia](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46061/la-tertulia) about ways to increase the [questions per day](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/14456/spanish-language). As of writing, we are on 4.4 and we are aiming to be over 5 steadily, like we have done [sometimes in the past](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2537/1674).

For this, we thought on opening a new game consisting in nothing else but posting questions... as many consecutive days as possible!

Let's try it out for a week!

Starting **from Monday 16th October and until Sunday 22th**, the challenge is to post a well received question (that is, with a positive reputation and that remains open at the end of the challenge) every day for as many as 7 days in a row. The winner will be the person who is able to do so. And in case two or more can reach that tremendous goal, we can untie by comparing the net reputation of their questions, or views, or...

Let's remember that the aim is to get good, on-topic questions that increase the quality of the site and, ideally, bring more people to the community. For this, let's curate them by using good formatting, proper tags and useful titles!

What do you think?

---

### Español

En los últimos días hemos estado comentando en nuestra sala de chat [La Tertulia](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46061/la-tertulia) sobre las formas de aumentar las [preguntas por día](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/14456/spanish-language). Al momento de escribir esto estamos en 4.4 preguntas por día de media y aspiramos a pasar de 5, como hemos hecho otras veces [en el pasado](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2537/1674).

Para lograr eso hemos pensado en abrir un nuevo juego que consiste simplemente en publicar preguntas... ¡Tantos días consecutivos como sea posible!

¡Vamos a probarlo durante una semana!

A partir del lunes 16 de octubre y hasta el domingo 22, el desafío es publicar una pregunta bien recibida (es decir, con una reputación positiva y que permanezca abierta al final del desafío) todos los días durante 7 días consecutivos. El ganador será la persona que sea capaz de hacerlo. Y en caso de que dos o más persona alcancen esa meta podemos desempatar comparando la reputación neta de sus preguntas, o número de visitas, o...

Recordemos que el objetivo es obtener buenas preguntas que aumenten la calidad del sitio y a ser posible traigan más gente a la comunidad. Para lograrlo hagamos preguntas bien formateadas, con etiquetas adecuadas y títulos útiles.

¿Qué os parece?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## PODIO FINAL

1. [walen](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/13628), 7 días seguidos preguntando, con un total de 46 puntos.
2. [Charlie](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/12637), 7 días seguidos preguntando, con un total de 20 puntos.
3. [fedorqui](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/1674), 6 días seguidos preguntando (¡ay, los domingos!), con un total de 22 puntos.

Mención especial a [blonfu](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/14069), [Diego](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/5481), [disinter](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/17902), [iBug](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/17109), [jonathan x](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/12844), [José D.](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/5410), [Lisa Beck](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/12401), [Marie](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/17715), [Mauricio Martinez](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/17686), [mdewey](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/12155), [Pablo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/13101), [Rodrigo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/6915), [theonlygusti](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/14141), [Trillian](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/13022), [user17232](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/17232), [VeAqui](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/17560) por haber participado también con sus preguntas, ¡gracias!

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a great idea. I'll be sure to **look through questions that have already been posted** and try to see if there are any things that I have wondered about the language that haven't been asked yet.

(P.S.: I bolded this so that users are aware not to ask haphazardly to avoid duplication flags everywhere)

Answer (score 2):

### Rules (proposed)

#### Contest

1. The contest will be held from 2017-10-16 00:00:00 UTC to 2017-10-23 00:00:00 UTC.
2. Every user who posts at least one question during the contest is considered a participant and eligible as a winner.

#### Eligible questions

3. Only questions asked during the contest shall be taken into account. This will be checked using StackExchange's reported "asked" date for each question.
4. Users can post as many questions per day as they like; however, only one question per user and day shall be considered for the contest. See next point.
5. If a user posts more than one question on the same day, only the question with the highest score will be considered. If two or more of said user's questions share the highest score, then the oldest one among those with the highest score will be considered.
6. Deleted questions, closed questions and questions put on hold, will not be considered.

#### Winner

7. The winner will be decided based on StackExchange's reported data as of 2017-10-23 00:00:00 UTC.
8. The criteria for deciding the winner will be as follows, in descending order of importance (criteria lower on the list will only be checked if needed to break a tie):

   - Longest question posting streak.
   - Highest total score.
   - Highest score on a single question.
   - Highest total number of question views.
   - Highest number of views on a single question.
   - Highest total number of answers received.
   - Highest number of answers on a single question.

Comment: I completely agree with the proposed rules! Good job, walen :)

Comment: Only one thing left to decide... what does the winner win? :-)

Answer (score 2):

## Clasificación final

```
usuario     racha suma  máxima
------------------------------
walen         7    46    12
Charlie       7    20     5
fedorqui      6    22     6
Rodrigo       4    14     4
mdewey        4    12     4
user17232     2     4     2
Mauricio Mtnz 1     6     6 *
Marie         1     6     6
blonfu        1     4     4 *
iBug          1     4     4
Lisa Beck     1     4     4 *
Diego         1     3     3
disinter      1     3     3
Trillian      1     3     3
Pablo         1     2     2
José D.       1     1     1
theonlygusti  1     1     1
VeAquí        1     0     0
```

`*` rachas interrumpidas, por lo que cojo la mejor serie.

Pregunta con más visitas hasta la fecha: [Where does the expression "no hay tu tía" come from?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22811/1674) (1700 en el momento de escribir esto)

### Día 7 - domingo 22 octubre

Número de preguntas: 4

```
usuario      máxima  ¿cerrada?
------------------------------
user17232       2        no
Charlie         1        no
walen           0        no
```

**Preguntas en liza.**

Charlie

- [¿En qué países o contextos se sigue usando "vale" como despedida?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22874/1674)

user17232

- [¿De dónde viene la palabra "corrupia"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22875/1674)

walen

- [¿Hay alguna manera de enlazar búsquedas del CORDE o del NTTLE?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22878/1674)
- [Why is it "marciano" instead of "martiano" in Spanish?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22881/1674)

### Día 6 - sábado 21 octubre

Número de preguntas: 8

```
usuario      máxima  ¿cerrada?
------------------------------
walen           4        no
fedorqui        2        no
Charlie         2        no
Rodrigo         3        no
user17232       2        no
Trillian        3        no
theonlygusti    1        no
jonathan x      6        sí
```

**Preguntas en liza.**

Rodrigo

- [Origen de la expresión "toque de queda"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22854/1674)

walen

- [Where does the word "quicio" come from?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22856/1674)

jonathan x -- duplicada

- [Pronoun placement in "La Compuerta Número 12"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22858/1674)

theonlygusti

- [What is the name of the tense formed with "llevo + gerundio"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22859/1674)

Trillian

- [¿Cómo se dice "forehand" en un juego de cartas?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22863/1674)

user17232

- [¿De dónde viene la expresión "de buten"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22864/1674)

Charlie

- [When was "dios" pronounced "díos" in Spanish?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22868/1674)

fedorqui

- [¿Por qué decimos "presumir" y no "preasumir" para algo que asumimos preventivamente?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22869/1674)

### Día 5 - viernes 20 octubre

Número de preguntas: 6

```
usuario      máxima  ¿cerrada?
------------------------------
fedorqui        5        no
Charlie         4        no
Lisa Beck       4        no
walen           2        no
```

**Preguntas en liza.**

Charlie:

- [¿Es "qué es lo que" un galicismo? ¿Está aceptado?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22838/1674)
- [Are there any compound words (verb+noun) with the noun in singular?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22839/1674)

Lisa Beck:

- [What does "p.º" mean?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22840/1674)

walen:

- [Use of conditional tense to talk about past, non-conditional facts?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22842/1674)
- [Is there an official list of Spanish onomatopoeia?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22844/1674)

fedorqui:

- [¿Por qué "tío" designa cariñosamente a una persona próxima?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22848/1674)

### Día 4 - jueves 19 octubre

Número de preguntas: 9

Clasificación diaria:

```
usuario      máxima  ¿cerrada?
------------------------------
walen          12        no
iBug            4        no
Rodrigo         4        no
Charlie         3        no
fedorqui        3        no
mdewey          3        no
Mauricio Mtnz   4        no
```

### Día 3 - miércoles 18 octubre

Número de preguntas: 8

Clasificación diaria:

```
usuario      máxima  ¿cerrada?
------------------------------
walen          10        no
Charlie         5        no
blonfu          4        no
Rodrigo         4        no
fedorqui        2        no
mdewey          2        no
```

### Día 2 - martes 17 octubre

Número de preguntas: 16

Clasificación diaria:

```
usuario      máxima  ¿cerrada?
------------------------------
walen           8        no
Marie           6        no
Mauricio Mtnz   6        no
fedorqui        4        no
Lisa Beck       4        no
Diego           3        no
blonfu          3        sí
mdewey          3        no
Rodrigo         3        no
disinter        3        no
Charlie         2        no
Pablo           2        no
```

**Preguntas en liza.**

Diego

- [Connotaciones de "hacer padre" frente a "hacer madre" a alguien](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22746/1674)

walen

- [Is there a Spanish version of the saying "a New York minute"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22751/1674)
- [What is a "desavío"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22753/1674)

Charlie

- [¿Cuándo perdió el infinitivo el estatus de "modo"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22754/1674)
- [¿Qué fue antes: "carnaval" o "carnestolendas"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22757/1674)

blonfu

- [¿Puede haber signos de interrogación dentro de otros signos de interrogación?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22758/1674)

mdewey

- [History of different passive forms in Spanish](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22759/1674)

Pablo

- [¿Existe una palabra en español para el acto o práctica de crear continuamente nuevas palabras?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22760/1674)

Mauricio Martínez

- [¿Por qué la expresión "ser pan comido" significa fácil?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22762/1674)
- [¿Demasiado o demasiada?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22765/1674)

fedorqui

- [Why is it that Spanish people use "zas" to refer to rude, sarcastic, sharp, harsh or funny replies?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22763/1674)

Marie

- [¿Es congruente colocar "etc." en un enumeración usando "como"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22770/1674)

disinter

- [What's the best way to write the phrase "apply as a spot treatment"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22773/1674)

Lisa Beck

- [When writing a post to people you don't know, which form of address should you use: tú, usted, or ustedes?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22777/1674)

Rodrigo

- [¿Cómo se puede traducir "dongle" al español?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22780/1674)

### Día 1 - lunes 16 octubre

Número de preguntas: 10

Clasificación diaria:

```
usuario      máxima  ¿cerrada?
------------------------------
walen          10        no
fedorqui        6        no
mdewey          4        no
blonfu          4        no
Charlie         3        no
José D.         1        no
VeAqui          0        sí
```

**Preguntas en liza.**

Charlie

- [¿Cómo se originó la expresión "aquí hay gato encerrado"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22726/1674)
- [¿Se puede rimar de forma asonante una palabra llana con una esdrújula?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22727/1674)

walen

- [Does the expression "¡Epa!" have any kind of political connotation?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22728/1674)
- [How should I pronounce programming language names (like "Java") and technical terms (like "JSON") in Spanish?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22729/1674)

fedorqui

- [¿Qué quiere decir "hablar por boca de ganso"? ¿Cuál es su origen?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22731/1674)

mdewey

- [Saying "X years ago today" in Spanish](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22732/1674)

blonfu

- [¿A santo de qué hago esta pregunta?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22740/1674)

José D.

- ["admite que fuera" vs "admite que sería"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22741/1674)

VeAquí

- [Historia y figuras de la literatura del español colonial africano](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22743/1674)

Answer (score 1):

As Qui-Gon Jinn said:

> Remember, concentrate on the moment. **Ask**, don't think. Trust your instincts.

And later confirmed by Yoda:

> No. Try not. **Ask... or ask not**. There is no try.

And also by Gandalf:

> **Ask**, you fools!