# Could we keep Resources in the Sidebar whenever there's room for it, please?

Tags: soporte, meta, elementos-destacados

Could we keep [Resources for Learning Spanish](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2514/1674) in the Sidebar whenever there's room for it, please?  I think this question will help attract serious students of Spanish to the site, and will help them use the site wisely.

I wonder if this question's answers would help? [What is "Frequently Asked"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/50242/287826)  It talks about frequent posts and faq.

---

I asked at Meta.  Does [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/307376/287826) help?

---

An additional idea.  Take a look at this "Featured on Meta" in Sidebar.

[image: Look at the Sidebar]

Look at the Sidebar.  Nifty, no?

Comment: The stub I created had a very specific purpose, and was intended to be *minimalist* -- hence, the term "stub."  However, with guidance from some kind folks at Meta, that proposed workaround may no longer be needed.  Please see my updated answer, below.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is a good idea.

[Resources for learning Spanish](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2514/1674) is a great piece of information that we decided to move to the main site after discussing in [Proposal: move "Resources for learning" question to the main site](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2740/1674). So now we have [Resources for learning Spanish](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/23617/1674) in the main site, making the original one in Meta deprecated.

We can just feature items from Meta, and featuring something that is deprecated can create collision and confusion. As I mentioned in [my answer to the proposal](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2742/1674):

> The bad part of moving this question to the main site will be that the featured post won't be there anymore. Also, this will free a spot in the off-topic closing reasons.

So... I cannot see what else we can do. Probably it is time for a bookmark to the question about Resources in the main site :)

Comment: @walen la primera opción no me convence demasiado: una publicación de Meta con featured pero vacía y con un enlace a otra del sitio principal. Ya puestos, mejor ponerle una estrellita y se accede a ella desde los favoritos como usuario. En [¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) podemos añadir texto, ahí sí podría estar bien.

Comment: @walen los visitantes no registrados no ven la sección _featured_ (al menos a mí no me sale si entro sin logarme). Entiendo la preocupación, yo soy el primero que usaba mucho ese acceso directo, pero no acabo de ver una solución fácil.

Comment: @walen ¡buena idea! Sigue quedando lejos en cuanto a número de clics hasta llegar, pero es un buen lugar.

Answer (score 1):

After further research on Meta, another approach appears to be possible, analogous to the "professional disclaimers" that have been prominently posted at Law, Health and Mi Yodeya.

Here is more information: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3883

Also, it might be possible to use the "Events" feature, with a repeating daily event that expires far in the future.  Please see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/307391/287826.

Comment: I am against using _Events_ for this. It is exactly the same as _featured_ only that it is not... an even :) We used this for [Preguntad, preguntad, malditos](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2713/1674) since it was something to be featured for a certain period.

Comment: Regarding using a professional disclaimer, well I don't think it is that important. I mean, just a tiny portion of the users of Spanish.SE com to seek Resources, so it looks a bit overkilling to me. Let's see what others think about it.

Comment: @fedorqui - There are two existing features of the software which we could harness for our purposes.  I don't think the *wording* has to include the word "event" or "professional disclaimer."   I think that custom language could be used in both cases.  But I'm not 100% certain because I don't have access to those tools. May I suggest that you try each one for one minute -- long enough to take a screenshot to share with the community?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to start the process of creating a workaround, with the suggestion that our moderators try it out to see if it works and then poll the community like it.

It will be a stub of a question on Meta that simply offers a redirection to the actual resources page.  It's a proof of concept, if you will.  A bit heavy-handed perhaps but my motto is *start somewhere*.

---

**Edit**: The Meta stub been created: [Resources for Learning Spanish](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2845/9385)

Could the moderators please post a link to it in the sidebar so the moderators and the community can evaluate the look and funcionality?